# Can someone figure out the damage equation in this game?

Tags: gods-lands-of-infnity

So there's this pretty obscure turn based RPG game called Gods Lands of Infinity. So there's a melee power of each character in this game. In this case, the Melee Power is 132. Each weapon also has a damage of their own, and in this case, the weapon damage is 9-11. Now, attacking on a enemy who has defense of -30, the damage output is 11-13. If the weapon's base damage is increased to 12-14, the damage output becomes 14-17.

Can someone figure out the damage equation in this game?